# Create new file with StreamWriter everytime the program is executed

Tags: c#, streamwriter

I am making simple tool for manipulating images in a database. I want to show the output result in a txt file and because the outcome may be different each time, I want the file to be rewritten with the fresh data every time the data is executed.

Also I want (if possible) to use some default location where the txt file will be created even though I have an `App.Config` file and that's also an option.

The problem I am having is with this code:

```
string Resultfile = 
    System.Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments) + 
    "\\PictureStatus.txt";

FileStream strm = new FileStream(Resultfile , FileMode.Create);

TextWriter tw = new StreamWriter(strm);
```

This populates the `PictureStatus.txt` only once and then I get the same text over and over again. I noticed that if I use some random destination the file is updated. Not sure if it's just random behavior or have something to do with using `MyDocuments`, but what I need is a way to be sure that I'll rewrite the file with the new data each time, and if possible, use some default destination that will work for other people.

Comment: Why rewrite a log file every time you run your process? Usually a log file will be changed appending to it (With date, time and description data)

Comment: Did you try `FileMode.Truncate`?

Comment: Agree with Steve. Use `FileMode.Append` with `FileStream`

Comment: Have you tried to run your app in admin ? Maybe your personal folder is protected. `FileMode.Create` is what answer to your need

Comment: Well it's very custom tool. And old Database is transfered and this tool if everything is ok will be ran only once. Anyways in case there is problem with some picture the they may need to use a couple of times, but once the transfer went well it's over what matter is the images that couldn't be transfer so each time I need to rewrite the data only with the images left to be transfered.

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this

```
public partial Form2 : Form 
{

public string path = Environment.CurrentDirectory + "/" + "Name.txt";

   public Form2()
   {

       InitializeComponent();

       if (!File.Exists(path))
       {
            File.Create(path);
       }

   }

     private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
     {

        using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(path, true))
        {
          sw.WriteLine("This text will be writen in the txt file", true);
          sw.Close();
        }
     }
}
```

I have add to the button, when I pressed it will be written in the next line every time. If you remove "true" from code, it will be overwritten every time.